# Scala extract from Seq of tuples

Tags: scala

Here's a `seq` of `tuples` in Scala

```
val t = Seq((1,2,3),(4,5,6))
```

I like to extract the first element of each tuple into its own sequence, i.e.,

```
Seq(1,4)
```

How do I do this in Scala?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply use `map` and transform each tuple to its first element:

```
t.map(x => x._1)
```

Or shorter:

```
t.map(_._1)
```

Comment: Or, if you prefer not to use the `_i` accessors: `t map { case (n, _, _) => n }`

Answer (score 6):

The general form to extract more than one columns:

```
def extractColumns3[T1, T2, T3](t: Seq[(T1, T2, T3)]): (Seq[T1],   Seq[T2], Seq[T3]) =
t.foldLeft((Seq.empty[T1], Seq.empty[T2], Seq.empty[T3])) { (columns, row) ⇒
  (columns._1 :+ row._1, columns._2 :+ row._2, columns._3 :+ row._3)
}
```

Comment: This solution has better performance for extracting more than one columns